# Creating a list of Or's and then filtering dataframe using that list Pandas/Python

Tags: python, list, filter, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
 Supplier  ProductDescription   Manufacturer
   Dell        computer              Dell
    N/A        Dell computer         N/A
   Apple       imac                 Apple
   OfficeMax   lenovo               lenovo ...etc
```

I want to filter out this dataframe by rows containing certain words but without double counting. So essentially, I want to keep these rows that contain 'Dell' or 'computer' or 'lenovo'.

To get:

```
   Supplier  ProductDescription   Manufacturer
   Dell        computer              Dell
    N/A        Dell computer         N/A
   OfficeMax   lenovo               lenovo
```

What I did was create a combined column :

```
  df['combine']=df.apply(lambda x:'%s,%s,%s' % (x['Supplier'],x['Product Description'],x['Manufacturer']),axis=1)
```

And then am trying to create a list to search and filter....

```
List=('Dell' or 'computer' or 'lenovo')
df=df[df['combine'].str.contains(List)]
```

However, when I run this code, I only get rows corresponding to the first value, Dell so the  code doesn't search for each word in the list.

Is there any other way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin`:

```
In [14]: df[df.isin(['Dell computer', 'Dell', 'computer', 'lenovo']).any(axis=1)]
Out[14]: 
    Supplier ProductDescription Manufacturer
0       Dell           computer         Dell
1        NaN      Dell computer          NaN
3  OfficeMax             lenovo       lenovo
```

I added a "Dell computer" option. You may want to regularize your names before doing this, if you expect them to be entered differently. This only matches exactly.